# Can we show that $\int\left|1_Bf-\int_Bf\:{\rm d}\lambda\right|^2\:{\rm d}\lambda\le c\int\left|f-\int f\:{\rm d}\lambda\right|^2\:{\rm d}\lambda$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, integral-inequality

Let $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, $f:E\to[0,\infty)^3$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable with $$\int|f|^2\:{\rm d}\lambda<\infty,\tag1$$ $k\in\mathbb N$ and $B_1,\ldots,B_k\in\mathcal E$ be disjoint with $$E=\bigcup_{i=1}^kB_i.\tag2$$

Are we able to derive a bound $$\max_{1\le i\le k}\int\left|1_{B_i}f-\int_{B_i}f\:{\rm d}\lambda\right|^2\:{\rm d}\lambda\le c\int\left|f-\int f\:{\rm d}\lambda\right|^2\:{\rm d}\lambda\tag3$$ for some $c\ge0$?

For example, if $\lambda$ is finite, $f=1_A$ (so, assuming it is scalar-valued) for some $A\in\mathcal E$ and $k=1$, $(3)$ reduces to \begin{equation}\begin{split}&\lambda(A\cap B)-2\left|\lambda(A\cap B)\right|^2+\lambda(E)\left|\lambda(A\cap B)\right|^2\\&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\le c\left(\lambda(A)-2|\lambda(A)|^2+\lambda(E)|\lambda(A)|^2\right).\end{split}\tag3\end{equation}

Comment: What is the first question in your post? Or is the question mark supposed to be a dot?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur It's supposed to be a dot, sorry.

Comment: First you assume $f: E \to [0,\infty)^3$ so $f$ takes values in $\Bbb R^3$ and then you try to use $f = 1_A$ which is a real value… your question is not clear in that point. And btw… if your function maps to $\Bbb R^3$ you cannot use the standard Lebesgue-integral which is defined for real valued functions…

Comment: @Gono Well, I'm obviously taking it to be a Bochner integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $(E,\mathcal{E})=([0,1],\mathcal{B}_{[0,1]})$ equipped with the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$, and $f\equiv 1$. Then
$$
\int\left|f-\int f\,d\lambda\right|^2\,d\lambda=0.
$$
However, for $B_1=[0,1/2]$ and $B_2=(1/2,1]$,
$$
\max_{1\le i\le 2}\int\left|f1_{B_i}-\int_{B_i} f\,d\lambda\right|^2\,d\lambda=1/4.
$$

Comment: Do you see any chance to uniformly bound the left-hand side of $(3)$ in an other way (such that the right-hand side does not depend on the $B_i$)?

Comment: I think you may take a multiple of $\int f^2$.

Comment: Hm, why do you think this might work? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Actually, my assertion requires finite $\lambda$.

Comment: That would still be interesting for me.

Comment: If $\lambda$ is a finite measure one may use the following inequality - $|h-g|^2\le 2(|h|^2+|g|^2)$ and the fact that  $L^2\subset L^1$.

Comment: The dash before your inequality is a bit confusing. But sure, I see. By nonnegativity, we even got $|h-g|\le h^2+g^2$ without the factor $2$. However, unfortunately I need a bound which tends to $0$ as $\int\left|f-\int f\:{\rm d}\lambda\right|^2\:{\rm d}\lambda$ goes to $0$. (Actually, in my application, the outer integrals $(3)$ are replaced by the measure with density $\frac1q\lambda$, where $q$ is a probability density on $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ with $\{q=0\}\subseteq\{f=0\}$, but I don't think that this makes a difference, does it?)

Comment: Do you think it might be worthwhile to think about bounding an other metric (instead of the $\max$) controlling the integrals on the left-hand side of $(3)$? Maybe the average or something?

Comment: Can you change the centering (of $f1_{B_i}$) on the RHS?

Comment: On the rhs there is no $1_{B_i}f$. Do you mean $1_Bf$? If so, change to what?

Comment: Isn't it $1_{B_i}f$ in eq $(3)$? Anyway, can you center $1_B f$ about $1_B\times \lambda(B)^{-1}\int _B f\,d\lambda$?

Comment: Sorry, there is no $1_Bf$. What I meant is that the $1_{B_i}f$ are on the left- not the right-hand side. If you mean to replace the $\int_{B_i}f\:{\rm d}\lambda$ by $\frac{1_{B_i}}{\lambda(B_i)}\int_{B_i}f\:{\rm d}\lambda$, how would this control the size of the left-hand side in a sensible way?

Comment: I believe that the modified LHS can be bounded by the "variance" of $f$.

Comment: I've described the actual problem I'm trying to solve here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3565518/47771. It would be great if you could take a look.

Comment: I finally managed that I'm indeed able to make the replacement you've suggested. How would you show the claim regarding the variance of $f$ you've mentioned?