# Can we show $\int_{B_i}\left|f-\frac1{λ(B_i)}\int_{B_i}f\:{\rm d}λ\right|^2\:{\rm d}λ\le\int\left|f-\frac1{λ(B)}\int f\:{\rm d}λ\right|^2\:{\rm d}λ$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, integral-inequality

Let $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, $f:E\to[0,\infty)^3$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable with $$\int|f|^2\:{\rm d}\lambda<\infty,\tag1$$ $k\in\mathbb N$ and $B_1,\ldots,B_k\in\mathcal E$ be disjoint with $$B:=\{f\ne0\}=\bigcup_{i=1}^kB_i\tag2$$ and $\lambda(B)\in(0,\infty)$.

Are we able to derive a bound $$\max_{1\le i\le k}\int_{B_i}\left|f-\frac1{\lambda(B_i)}\int_{B_i}f\:{\rm d}\lambda\right|^2\:{\rm d}\lambda\le c\int_B\left|f-\frac1{\lambda(B)}\int f\:{\rm d}\lambda\right|^2\:{\rm d}\lambda\tag3$$ for some $c\ge0$?

Using the idea described in the comments below [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3560918/47771), it should be useful to note that $(3)$ can be rewritten as $$\max_{1\le i\le k}\lambda(B_i)\operatorname{Var}_{\operatorname P_i}[f]\le c\lambda(B)\operatorname{Var}_{\operatorname P}[f]\tag4,$$ where $$\operatorname P_i:=\frac{1_{B_i}\lambda}{\lambda(B_i)}$$ and $$\operatorname P:=\frac{1_B\lambda}{\lambda(B)}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to check that $\int_\Omega |f - \sigma|^2 \, d \mu \leq \int \big|f - \frac{1}{\mu(\Omega)} \int_\Omega f\big|^2 \, d \mu$ for all $\sigma \in \Bbb{R}$.

Therefore, setting $\sigma_i := \frac{1}{\lambda(B_i)} \int_{B_i} f d \lambda$ and $\sigma := \frac{1}{\lambda(B)}\int_B f \, d \lambda$, we see
$$
\int_{B_i}
|f - \sigma_i|^2
d \lambda
\leq \int_B |f - \sigma_i|^2 d \lambda
\leq \int_B |f - \sigma|^2 \, d \lambda,
$$
which proves your inequality with $c = 1$.

Comment: Ah, sure. For every Hilbert space (say $H$) valued random variable $X$, $$\varphi:H\to\mathbb R\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto\operatorname E\left[\left\|X-x\right\|_H^2\right]$$ is minimal at $x=\operatorname E[X]$. Forgot that for a moment. Do you see any chance to generalize this to the case $\lambda(B)=\infty$ (where we cannot normalize the trace of the measure)? Of course, with the right-hand side of $(3)$ accordingly replaced.

Comment: I guess you didn't noticed that there was a $B$ missing in the subscript of the outer integral on the right-hand side of my equation $(3)$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: No, i didn't notice that. But this would only make the inequality easier to derive, since $\int_B |f - \sigma|^2 d \lambda \leq \int |f -\sigma|^2 d\lambda$. Also, I didn't actually note that your function is vector valued, but it shouldn't make a difference. For your question with B of infinite measure, I am not sure. What do you mean by "the right-hand side of (3) accordingly replaced"?

Comment: Should the first inequality be reversed? I mean that
$$
\int_\Omega |f - \sigma|^2 \, d \mu \geq \int \big|f - \frac{1}{\mu(\Omega)} \int_\Omega f\big|^2 \, d \mu?
$$

Comment: @RobertW. No, the inequality follows from the argument in my first comment applied for the probability measure $\operatorname P$ (in the question) and $X=f$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d But $\mu(\Omega)^{-1}\int_{\Omega}fd\mu$ is $\operatorname E[X]$ in your notation, isn't it?

Comment: @RobertW. That's correct.

Comment: @PhoemueX My actual concern is slightly (and I really hope only *slightly*) more complicated than the task described in the question. Since it's too long for a comment, I've asked a separate question for that: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3566966/47771.